# "should + PRESENT PROGRESSIVE" vs "should + PRESENT"

Tags: tense

I was wondering about the difference in meaning between the below two sentences, which only differ in their tenses. I came across the first sentence in [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/JrzumXTQQ2M?t=308) explaining the five things to know before you start acupuncture, and I don't know what the difference is if it is said like the second sentence instead.

#1 "Who then should be getting acupuncture?"

#2 "Who then should get acupuncture?"

Comment: Thanks for the video link. Can you tell us what you already know about the difference between present simple and present continuous?

Comment: [correction: the two sentences below]. The then implies a prior conversation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing there is a group of people.

Hearing the first sentence

1. "Who then should be getting acupuncture?"

I will presume that it is imperative that someone from this group should get acupuncture.

Hearing the second sentence

2. "Who then should get acupuncture?"

I would presume that one (anyone) from this group would get an acupuncture. It may be that in this second instance someone volunteered for acupuncture and then changed his/her mind, now acupuncturist is asking the group who should get acupuncture based on group decision.

I have seen the video. The narrator is  essentially asking, "if anyone is willing for acupuncture, should he/she be getting acupuncture?". Then she proceeded to list the criteria for the person who should be getting acupuncture.

If a person fulfills the listed criteria, then that person should be getting acupuncture. Otherwise not.